# Ошибка Laravel при отправке данных из формы комментария - MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225:

Tags: php, laravel, framework, фреймворк

Здравствуйте!

Все отлично добавляется через `php artisan tinker` и можно увидеть комментарии на странице указанного `post_id`. Но с отправкой через форму какая-то беда, может была у кого такая проблема?

Версия **Laravel 5.4**.

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.2 (PHP 5.6.23 тАФ cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $c = new Photo\Comment;
=> Photo\Comment {#653}
>>> $c->body = 'Hellom a,ff!';
=> "Hellom a,ff!"
>>> $c->post_id = 15;
=> 15
>>> $c->save();
=> true
```

Вот такая ошибка вылезла при отправке данных из формы комментария:

```
MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225: body

in Model.php line 225
at Model->fill(array('body' => 'gdfgdfgd', 'post_id' => 21)) in Model.php line 145
at Model->__construct(array('body' => 'gdfgdfgd', 'post_id' => 21)) in Model.php line 268
и тд.
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comments', 'CommentsController@store');
```

**CommentsControllers.php**

```
namespace Photo\Http\Controllers;

use Photo\Post;
use Photo\Comment;

class CommentsController extends Controller
    {
        protected $guarded = [];
        public function store(Post $post)
        {
          Comment::create([
            'body' => request('body'),
            'post_id' => $post->id
         ]);
         return back();
    }
}
```

**post.blade.php**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <form method="post" action="/posts/{{$post->id}}/comments">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="body" placeholder="Ваш комментарий" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">Опубликовать</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут несколько вариантов решения:

1. В модели `Photo\Comment` перечислить поля для заполнения в массиве `protected $fillable = [];` (в вашем случае это: `body`, `post_id` и возможно ещё какие-то, какие у вас там есть).
2. Или вместо:

   ```
   Comment::create([
           'body' => request('body'),
           'post_id' => $post->id
        ]);
   ```

   писать через объект:

   ```
   $comment = Photo\Comment;
   $comment->post_id = $post->id;
   $comment->body = request('body');
   $comment->save();
   ```